# When to update tableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am building a to-do list app where I use my section headers to show information about the process. through string manipulation, I show some values in there about To-do. But to always be up to date I only know the `reloadData()` command. But it looks really bad trying to deleteRows automatically.

So my question is how to make the headers text update in a clean way, not through `reloadData()`.

This is where you mark your To-do as done:

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .default, handler: { (action) in

        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            self.goals.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        } else {
            self.goalsB.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        }
        self.counter+=1
        self.saveDefaults()
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }))
```

And this is where my Header gets set:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.textColor = UIColor.white
    label.backgroundColor = section == 0 ? UIColor(red: 41 / 255.0, green: 76 / 255.0, blue: 103 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0) : UIColor(red: 235 / 255.0, green: 108 / 255.0, blue: 33 / 255.0, alpha: 0.5)

    if section == 0 {

        label.text = "     \(counter) goals completed / \(goals.count) outstanding"

    }

    return label
}
```

Comment: you may try 
tableView.beginUpdate()
tableView.endUpdate()
instead of reload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know in advance which particular section's header has to be updated , you can use TableView.reloadSection() method.

Comment: what are the parameters though?

Comment: TableView.reloadSection((Indexset of sections) ,UITableViewRowAnimation)

Comment: Example if you want to reload section 1 - Use  TableView.reloadSections([1], with: .automatic)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the transition api on `UIView`.

```
UIView.transition(with: label,
              duration: 0.25,
               options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
               animations: { [weak self] in
                  self?.label.text = "\(counter) goals completed / \(goals.count) outstanding"
         }, completion: nil)
```